# Django admin site users model limitations

Tags: python, django, admin, models

i am really new to Django, but since i am doing a fairly easy app i was suggested by a friend to use only the admin site which is fast and easy, i am almost done with my project, but i need one thing i don't seem to find anywhere.

My model is about adding programming problems, however i need to have a field that identifies which user added it and that only that user and the super users can erase or change the problem he just added.

Of course adding the field is quite simple, however how do i recognize who is adding the problem? and how to validate only him and the super users can change or delete that said problem?. I believe this is the most challenging phase of this project, can you help me?.

Thanks in advance :)!

EDIT: this is what i tried after the answer i just got recently, but i am quite stuck :/

EDIT2: this is now how it looks, but it gives my a type error and brings down the whole adminsite with this :

"has_change_permission() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"

EDIT3: now i have changed the code but it still let regular staff users to erase delete entries, and sadly now it gives the error in EDIT 2 when i try to modify the content of the entry.

EDIT4: Finally thanks to your help i could make it impossible for a common user to delete directly on the database, however the default delete by queryset still works for them, what can i do?

EDIT5: Thanks for all the help you gave me today, now it works and it is wonderful! i leave the code so someone else with this same issue can just do it, i had to do such a long research to get rid of the "delete_element" from django's admin the one that is setted as default.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Problemas
# Register your models here.
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected as delete_selected_


def delete_selected(modeladmin,request,queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        if (obj.User==request.user.username or request.user.is_superuser):
            obj.delete()



class ProblemasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Juez', 'Nombre', 'Categoria','Dificultad','URL','User')
    list_filter = ('Juez','Categoria','Dificultad','User')
    search_fields = ['Nombre']
    readonly_fields = ('User',)
    list_per_page = 20
    actions = [delete_selected]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if (obj.User==""):
            obj.User = request.user.username
        obj.save()


    def delete_model(self,request,obj):
        for o in obj.all():
            if (o.User==request.user.username or request.user.is_superuser):
                o.delete()

    def has_change_permission(self,request,obj=None):
        return obj==None or request.user.username == obj.User or request.user.is_superuser
    def has_delete_permission(self,request,obj=None):
        return obj==None or request.user.username == obj.User or request.user.is_superuser

admin.site.register(Problemas,ProblemasAdmin)
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Deeper modifications: Adding row-level permissions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-django-admin/#N10260)

Comment: You were almost there. Just place those `has_change_permission` and `has_delete_permission` inside your `ProblemasAdmin` and remove the `Checker` class, which is not really needed. And remember to handle the case `obj=None` or you will get errors!

Comment: Hi, i edited my question again. However now it gives a type error which i find weird since i am validating the case where i am not in a table (obj=None) ): , i am reading the link you gave me, thanks!

Comment: `obj` is an optional argument. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission

Answer (score 0):

```
@register(QuestionModel)
class QuestionModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     def has_change_permission(self,request,obj=None):
         return request.user == obj.owner
     def has_delete_permission(self,request,obj=None):
         return request.user == obj.owner
```

I think should work

Comment: Nitpick: `obj` may be `None`

Comment: I saw that ... but im not sure under what circumstances it would be none ... so I figure the logic is easier with just one condition also ...

Comment: It can be `None` when rendering the changelist (i.e. the list of questions), and in other occasions that I can't remember

Comment: @RodolfoJoséMiquilarena put your model in the original question along with what you tried ...

Comment: Thanks for your help!, however i don't know what to do with this, i mean how do i call for it in my ProblemModelAdmin?

Comment: this is your `ProblemModelAdmin` I just called it `QuestionModelAdmin` cause I had no idea what you named your models ... see my previous comment...

Comment: i edited my question , however i am quite stuck on how to return the class properly.

Comment: I have a meeting I will look at it again when I get back

Comment: your `ProblemasAdmin` looks right try putting a print statement in the functions to make sure they are getting called ...

Comment: oh change it to `def has_change_permission(self,request,obj=None):` in both functions

Comment: Hi i just edited again , it is not giving the error, but it still let common staff users erase entries that are from other users.

Comment: try adding some print statements ... or use breakpoints ... the only reason a user can erase is if that returns true

Comment: @RodolfoJoséMiquilarena: in `save_model` you're using `obj.added_by`, while in `has_*_permission` you're using `obj.owner`

Comment: hello i managed to solve the issues i had adding the field 'User' and other things ill edit with my progress! now a common user can't directly delete, but he can still delete in cascade queryset, do you have any suggestions on that? thanks!

Comment: I solved the issue, thank you so much for all your help